# Run TensorBoard on Colab

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I have following code

```py
!pip install timm

import timm
from torchsummary import summary
import torchvision.models as models
import torch 
import os
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

%load_ext tensorboard
#model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=False)

model = timm.create_model('inception_v4', pretrained=False)
#model.cuda()

summary(model, (3, 440, 440))
writer=SummaryWriter('/content/logsdir')

%tensorboard --logdir /content/logsdir
```

When the code is run, there is error as No graph definition files were found. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the **full** error backtrace?

Comment: can you run `!ls /content/` and `!ls /content/logsdir`  in a cell after running this?
i also suggest trying wandb.ai instead of tensorboard for better experiment tracking

Comment: @tnfru I tried but still the same. I run `!ls /content/ and !ls /content/logsdir` after running the above code.

Comment: @Ivan could you run the code in Colab. This code doesn't need anything and can just run in Colab straight

Comment: I did run it, and it launches the embedded Tensorboard window properly. It probably means the issue is on your end...

Answer (score 0):

Use *Built-in magic commands* https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Read reference document at https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb